# AspectJ autoproxy issues with Spring Controllers and Webflow Actions

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-webflow, autoproxy

I have two related issues regarding spring/AspectJ AOP. I have a typical logger aspect which logs exceptions thrown from any class in my application including services, daos, controllers and webflow actions...

```
@Aspect
public class AspectLogger {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.myapp..*.*(..))", throwing = "t")
    public void logGustavoException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable t) {

        Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        logger.error(t.getMessage(), t);
    }
}
```

In my application context I have an equally typical configuration...

```
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- AOP logging config --> 
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="aspectLogger" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean id="aspectLogger" class="com.myapp.AspectLogger" />
```

This works fine for the most part, the issue I have is with the webflow actions and controllers which implement an interface.

**1 - Controllers which implement an Interface...**

One of our controllers implements an interface which defines one method, as well as defining several public methods which are used as @RequestMapping handlers...

```
@Controller
public class AmazingController implements OutstandingInterface {

    // implements the method from OutstandingInterface
    @Override
    public Object doSomethingOutstanding(){
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/amazingUrl.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSomethingAmazing(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
        return "anAmazingViewName";
    }

    ...
}
```

The issue here is that due to the fact that the controller implements an interface that doesn't define all its public methods (i.e. controller request mapping methods), a proxy is created for the controller which only proxies the 'doSomethingOutstanding' method from OutstandingInterface. As such, when a request comes in to /amazingUrl.htm, Spring does not route it to the appropriate request handler - it's as though the request mapping doesn't exist. *I have solved this by defining an interface for the controller which extends OutstandingInterface and also defines the request handler methods required by the controller, but it seems odd/wrong to me to have to define an interface for a controller just so that the AspectJ stuff doesn't 'hide' the request handler*...

```
@Controller
public interface IAmazingController extends OutstandingInterface{

    @RequestMapping(value="/amazingUrl.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSomethingAmazing(HttpSession session, ModelMap model);

}

...

public class AmazingController implements IAmazingController {

    @Override
    public Object doSomethingOutstanding(){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value="/amazingUrl.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSomethingAmazing(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
        return "anAmazingViewName";
    }

    ...
}
```

**2 - Webflow Actions**

The second issue is very similar. After introducing the AspectJ configuration, none of my webflow Action classes were being autowired correctly - I kept getting 'cannot find bean of type FantasticAction' sort of errors. Again, I introduced interfaces for all of the Action classes and this solved the problem as it was the proxy that was being injected at runtime, not the actual action implementation class.

*So finally...* the question in both instances is - is there a way of getting around these AspectJ issues without having to define interfaces for every class I want to advise?

Answer (score 2):

You should add CGLIB dependendy in your class path so you will not need to create interfaces for working with AOP

Take a look to the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08s06.html).

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a dependency on CGLIB already but it doesn't appear to create proxies for webflow actions. Regarding the controller, I removed the requirement for AmazingController to implement OutstandingInterface (refactored into a service) so this removes the workaround to have to define an interface for AmazingController - much nicer this way.